# Use of field and script in Facet

Tags: elasticsearch

I am new in elastic search. I am trying to understand this query but I could not succed in few things like field and script. I read official documents and get that Facet has been removed my aggregation and Attributelabels is a facet name but I could not understand full query. Can anyone explain it to me ?
Thank you

```
{
  "size" : 0,
  "facets" : {
    "AttributeLabels" : {
      "terms" : {
        "field" : "field",
        "size" : 50,
        "script" : "scriptName",
        "lang" : "lang"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.4/search-facets-terms-facet.html

**Field** - The field that the facet is evaluated on

**Size** - The number of top terms that are returned

**Script** - Either returns a string `"term + 'aaa'"` which becomes the term that is evaluated on or a boolean `"term == 'aaa'  ? true : false"` which includes or excludes it from the facet collection

**Lang** - The scripting language used

But if you can, I recommend upgrading to Elasticsearch 2. :)